# Rails: authentication website and mobile app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, authentication

I want develop an authentication system from website and mobile app.

For the sign up i have follow this tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Now i want also that a mobile app can sign up through json.

How can handle the remember me function for client website and mobile app? The website can use the cookie and rails can use a before_filter to check if the user exists. But how can use a before_filter to differentiate the request incoming from website or mobile app? (i suppose that the mobile app doesn't use cookie but a token maybe)

Thanks u all